# What is clearance of psoriatic plaques?

Tags: psoriasis

I have read this in the [Psoriasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psoriasis) article in Wikipedia:

> Moisturizers and emollients such as mineral oil, petroleum jelly, calcipotriol, and decubal (an oil-in-water emollient) were found to increase the clearance of psoriatic plaques

What is clearance of psoriatic plaques?

Comment: The article (as the quoted text) talks about the clearance of psoriasis *plaques*, not of psoriasis. Do you get the difference? Did you look at what a psoriasis plaque is? What do you imagine clearance means in the context?

Comment: Yes and yes. I don't imagine anything in the context.

Comment: Clearance is just what one would imagine in almost any dermatological condition: some degree of resolution. Psoriasis is a disease, one manifestation of which is plaques. Topical treatment can't cure psoriasis.

Comment: @kature Can you figure it out from context of all the other uses of the word "clear" in that paragraph?

Comment: @BryanKrause no, I didn't figure that out. It might has to do with the fact that English is not my mother tongue (nor any other Germanic language).

Answer (score 1):

[Clearance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clearance) is "an act or process of clearing".

[Clear](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clear) in this context is "CLEAN, PURE" as in "free from blemishes".

Clearance of psoriatic plaques would indicate the plaques are going away; "increase the clearance" indicates going away faster (though no statement is made here about appearance of *new* plaques).

There are other hints in the paragraph you quote from like:

> more effective at **clearing** psoriatic plaques

> Medicated creams and ointments applied directly to psoriatic plaques can help reduce inflammation, remove built-up scale, reduce skin turnover, and **clear affected skin** of plaques